# How do I use add_control to offer a list of all pages in the customiser?

Tags: theme-customizer, theme-options

What I am trying to do is offer three pages to highlight on the front page. To do this, I would like to offer users a dropdown list of all pages.

I have not worked out how to do this.

I know how to get the pages `get_theme_mod( 'mytheme_user_page_1', '' )` is probably about right.

How do I set up the control?

```
$wp_customize->add_setting( 'mytheme_user_page_1', array(
    'default' => ''
) );

$wp_customize->add_control( array(
    'type' => 'range',
    'section' => 'my_custom_section', 
    'label' => __( 'Pick a page, bub' ),
    // something magical here 
) );
```

## Update

I probably did not make this very clear (my bad) I also need to know how to populate the dropdown control. (Or not, see below - I might have missed a trick or two before).

Thanks to a link in the comments and then another link telling me to open my eyes (only far more polite than perhaps I deserved) I did see what was being pointed out. The manual says only this:

> - **dropdown-pages** (use the allow_addition argument to allow users to add
>     new pages from the control)

That's every mention of both terms on the entire page. Maybe I am tired (that is quite likely) but I am struggling to understand how and why this works.

I only found it because I did a text search of the page for "drop" and got 1/1 results. Given the comments does this mean this populates a list of pages? And, if so, what on earth is the `allow_addition` argument? (And how do I use it?)

I am starting to suspect that I could chuck a bunch of stuff into my control and hope for the best. Something like this:

```
'type'=>'dropdown-pages',
'argument'=>'allow_addition', //maybe
'allow_addition'=>TRUE, //possibly
```

or

```
'type'=>array('dropdown-pages','allow_addition'), // ?? I'm just guessing
```

I would prefer to know why I have done it and what is happening here because I will feel obligated to support any themes I release. Responding to a question with, "TBH, I have no idea what I am doing" is not something I want in any possible future.

I apologise if I am being a bit slow today.

I would really appreciate someone taking a few minutes to help me understand. If you could explain the `allow_addition` argument while you are at it I will forever be in your debt.

Comment: See [this](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/customize-api/customizer-objects/#controls).

Comment: I know how to add a control. How do I add a list of all pages as a control?

Comment: @MatthewBrownakaLordMatt See Sally's link. `dropdown-pages` is an accepted `type` for a control.

Comment: How many times have I been on that page and not seen it? Thank you for being patient with me. I'm still struggling (see update) but I at least have a clue.

Comment: You don’t need to populate it. Just set the type to dropdown-pages and you’ll get a dropdown with a list of pages. That’s it. I suggest just trying it.

Comment: Maybe I am over-thinking this. I'll go play and come back if/when I have questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To add a Customiser control for selecting a page from a dropdown you just need to set the `type` argument to `dropdown-pages`:

```
$wp_customize->add_control( array(
    'type'    => 'dropdown-pages',
    'section' => 'my_custom_section', 
    'label'   => __( 'Pick a page, bub' ),
) );
```

This will give you a control that's a `<select>` dropdown with a list of pages automatically populated. When saved it will save the post ID of the page, or `0` if none is selected.

The `'allow_addition'` argument is an additional argument that can be passed to `$wp_customize->add_control()` when using `dropdown-pages` that will allow the user to create a page from the Customiser, just like with the settings in the *Home page settings* section of the Customiser. You would use this argument like this:

```
$wp_customize->add_control( array(
    'type'           => 'dropdown-pages',
    'allow_addition' => true,
    'section'        => 'my_custom_section', 
    'label'          => __( 'Pick a page, bub' ),
) );
```