# How do I get information about a page, such as featured image, except, and title?

Tags: theme-development, pages

Assuming that I learn how to do [this](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/341842/109240), how do I pull information about the user's selected page and display them?

Obviously, I start with

```
$mytheme_f_page[1] = get_theme_mod( 'mytheme_featured_page_1', '' );
```

What do I do to pull the information about this page? As there will be three, can I get all three at once or do I need to do it one at a time?

I'm going to need the thumbnail, the title, and the excerpt.

Comment: You could store the page ID and use functions like `get_the_title()` and `get_the_excerpt()`. You could also store an array of page IDs and loop over the array to get the post data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you save a selected page in the Customiser you're just saving the post ID of the page, which means you can just pass that value to any function that accepts a post ID as a parameter:

```
$mytheme_f_page[1] = get_theme_mod( 'mytheme_featured_page_1' );

echo get_the_title( $mytheme_f_page[1] );
echo get_the_excerpt( $mytheme_f_page[1] );
echo get_the_post_thumbnail( $mytheme_f_page[1] );
```

The first time you use any one of these the full post (page) is  cached internally, so you don't need to worry about getting them one at a time or all at once, or anything like that.

Comment: That seems straight forward. I was expecting this to be much harder.